# How to parse column values with SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, string, oracle, csv, recursive-query

I am using ORACLE ( version ? ).

I have a table mytable with a column COL_LIST containing concatenated values separated by '/' :

```
COL_LIST

06130/06520
06000/06100/06200/06300
```

Using SQL, I would like to create another table with COL_LIST and a new column COL such as :

```
COL    COL_LIST

06130  06130/06520
06520  06130/06520
06000  06000/06100/06200/06300
06100  06000/06100/06200/06300
06200  06000/06100/06200/06300
06300  06000/06100/06200/06300
```

Using :

```
SELECT col_list ,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( col_list , '[^/]+' , 1 , LEVEL )  AS col
  FROM mytable
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR( col_list , '[^/]+' , 1 , LEVEL ) IS NOT NULL
```

works fine if I have only one value ( for example 06130/06520 ) in COL_LIST of MYTABLE but if not the result is not what I expected.

Any hints about the case?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `connect by` like that: it duplicates the rows and does not yield the results you want.

Starting from your existing query, and assuming Oracle 12c or higher, you can work around this with a lateral join:

```
select t.col_list, x.col
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select regexp_substr(t.col_list , '[^/]+', 1, level) as col
    from dual
    connect by regexp_substr(t.col_list , '[^/]+', 1, level) is not null
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't on 12c or above, then:

```
SQL> select regexp_substr(col_list, '[^/]+', 1, column_value) col,
  2         col_list
  3  from mytable cross join
  4    table(cast(multiset(select level
  5                        from dual
  6                        connect by level <= regexp_count(col_list, '/') + 1
  7                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
  8  order by col_list desc, col;

COL        COL_LIST
---------- -----------------------
06130      06130/06520
06520      06130/06520
06000      06000/06100/06200/06300
06100      06000/06100/06200/06300
06200      06000/06100/06200/06300
06300      06000/06100/06200/06300

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this solution:

```
SELECT distinct col_list col_lst, REGEXP_SUBSTR( col_list , '[^/]+' , 1 , LEVEL ) col_val,  level lvl
  FROM col_single
CONNECT BY level <=  REGEXP_count( col_list , '[^/]+' , level)
order by col_lst desc, lvl;
```